# PDO - Insert blob image into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I have some problems

> Notice: Array to string conversion in x\contact_ajouter_verif.php on line 17

This is my form :

```
<form action="contact_ajouter_verif.php" method="post" name="ajoutContact" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <fieldset>
        <label>Nom :</label> <input size="30%" type="text" placeholder="" name="nom" /> 
        <label>Numéro :</label> <input size="30%" type="number" placeholder="" name="num" />
        <label>Image au format png :</label><input type="file" name="img" />
    </fieldset> 
    &nbsp;<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Ajouter"/>
</form>
```

And this is my pdo receiver page:

```
<?php
include('../inc/connexion.inc.php');
include('session.php');

$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
$img = $_FILES['img'];

$pseudo = $user_check. "_contact";
$rqt1= "INSERT INTO $pseudo(CTC_NOM, CTC_NUMERO, CTC_IMG) VALUES(:nom, :num, :img)";
$result1 =$cnxpdo->prepare($rqt1);
$result1->execute(array(
    'nom' => "$nom",
    'num' => "$num",
    'img' => "$img" //line 17
)); 
?>
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, please if someone have the solution :)

Comment: `VALUES($nom` failed you.

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: `$nom` is not a binding.

Comment: thx but still this one : Notice: Array to string conversion in x\contact_ajouter_verif.php on line 17

Comment: Update the question to your new code..

Comment: Updated, sry I'm new

Comment: @Drobulo basically you just have to have an idea what are you doing. Ask yourself, what are you trying to get from `$img = $_FILES['img']`. Then re-read the manual page on file uploads

Answer (score 1):

Finally found for those in the same case than me (unlikely but we never know...) :

```
<?php
include('../inc/connexion.inc.php');
include('session.php');

$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
$img =addslashes(file_get_contents ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));



$pseudo = $user_check. "_contact";
$rqt1= "INSERT INTO $pseudo(CTC_NOM, CTC_NUMERO, CTC_IMG) VALUES(:nom, :num, :img)";
$result1 =$cnxpdo->prepare($rqt1);
$result1->execute(array(
    'nom' => "$nom",
    'num' => "$num",
    'img' => "$img"
));

?>
```

Thanx for your help.